# Rendering Choice, Date and User values in Sharepoint 2013 REST API (without knockout)

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest

I have researched this topic, but I can't find a solution for multiple list items needing `$expand:`.

The script is below, with the following fields:

1. `Title`: text/Name of the Company
2. `CompanyStatus`: choice/Datatable is filtered from this, so it renders properly
3. `CompanyClass`: choice/This shows up as [object object]
4. `Modified`: date/This shows up as unfriendly date format
5. `EditorId`: user/This shows up as a numeric value

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">

   function LoadTitles(companystatus)
   {
       var call = $.ajax({
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Companies')/items?"+
   "$select=Title,CompanyStatus,CompanyClass,Modified,EditorId&$filter=(CompanyStatus eq '"+companystatus+"')&$top=5000",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       headers: {
           Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }

   });
   call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
       $('#example').dataTable({
           "bDestroy": true,
           "bProcessing": true,
           "aaData": data.d.results,
           "aoColumns": [
               { "mData": "Title" },
               { "mData": "CompanyStatus" },
       { "mData": "CompanyClass" },
               { "mData": "Modified" },
               { "mData": "EditorId" }
           ]
         });
   });
   call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
       alert("Error retrieving Tasks: " + jqXHR.responseText);
   });
   }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `CompanyClass` is a multi-valued choice field, the following example demonstrates how to retrieve the specified field values.

First of all, change your query to request `Editor` properties such as `Title` (SharePoint REST by default returns User field id, in your case `EditorId` field )

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Companies')/items?"+
"$select=Title,CompanyStatus,CompanyClass,Modified,Editor/Title&$filter=(CompanyStatus eq '"+companystatus+"')&$top=5000&$expand=Editor"
```

Then apply the following changes to data source and mapping for `.dataTable`:

```
var tableData = data.d.results.map(function(item){
        item['EditorTitle'] = item['Editor']['Title']; //extract Editor Title
        item['CompanyClassTitles'] = item['CompanyClass'].results.join(','); //concat multiple choice field values
        return item;
    }); 

    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aaData": tableData,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "Title" },
            { "mData": "CompanyStatus" },
            { "mData": "CompanyClassTitles" },
            { "mData": "Modified" },
            { "mData": "EditorTitle" }
        ]
      });
```

Comment: Hi, apologies for late reply, but thak you for responding and helping me. Does the var tableData script above replace the 'call done' function or go under it?

Comment: Hi, second option: goes under it. The intention of  tableData is to prepare proper data for dataTable

Comment: Thanks -- I'm going to try it out and get back to you asap

Comment: I got the following error: "DataTables warning (tableid = 'example'): Requested unknown parameter 'EditorId' from the data source". Nothing has changed in the results, and [object][object] is still there, and nothing is coming up under the 'Last Modified' column.

Comment: Have you noticed i changed .dataTable intitialization (column names)?

Comment: I did notice that -- I copied your code directly. Was I not supposed to do that?

Comment: Should I have changed the existing column titles to the NEW titles you used in your script -- within the SharePoint Application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the fields that point to users, according your call:

```
$select=Title,CompanyStatus,CompanyClass,Modified,Editor/Id,Editor/Title[or Name],Editor/EMail&expand=Editor
```

Whit that you will get all the information of the user.

For the field *CompanyClass* it is an array and you can get the values like this:

```
data.d.results[0].Choices.results;
```

Where results is the array.
And finally the dates, I use moment.js to format it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response -- unfortunately, it didnt't work, and I keep getting errors:It's saying the expression isn't valid. Also, Where do I put the dad.d result part in the script?

Comment: Please paste your rest uri to check it out

Comment: **Here is the updated REST, as per your edits** url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +        "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Companies')/items?"+"$select=Title,CompanyStatus,CompanyClass,Modified,Editor/Id,Editor/Title[or Name],Editor/EMail&
 $expand=Editor&
 $filter=(CompanyStatus eq '"+companystatus+"')&$top=5000",

Comment: **Here is the updated d.dat part, as per you edits**  "aaData": data.d.results, data.d.results[0].Choices.results;
        "aoColumns": [

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a mess-up on my end, so thank you for being patient and helping me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was on holidays.
but you didnt change the /Title[or Name] i write that because I dont remember the field name.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - the above join for multiple choice didn't work for me on SP 2010 as results array contained an object with a "Value" properties that held the value.

I replaced:

```
item['CompanyClassTitles'] = item['CompanyClass'].results.join(','); //concat multiple choice field values
```

with

```
item['CompanyClassTitles'] = item['CompanyClass'].results.map(function(elem){
    return elem.Value;
}).join(",");
```

Not sure if the same applies to SP 2013 but wanted to mention it in case it could be useful to someone out there...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Very much appreciated.